# Posting to Facebook specific friend list using Facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, privacy, posting

I am successfully posting to Facebook wall, but I want that user can choose whether they want to post it to some specific friend list e.g. Acquaintances, Family etc

My code is giving this error :

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) privacy must contains a valid privacy 'value'","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

I have added "privacy" attribute and have given it value of "Family", but its not working, but if I remove the privacy attribute, the wall post is successful

```
try
        {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", msg);
            parameters.putString("description", "Test 1");
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("value", "Family");
            parameters.putString("privacy", jsonObject.toString());
            response = Data.facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The value field may specify one of the following strings: 
>   EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, CUSTOM .
>
> The friends field must be specified if value is set to CUSTOM and
>   contain one of the following strings: EVERYONE, NETWORKS_FRIENDS (when
>   the object can be seen by networks and friends), FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS,
>   ALL_FRIENDS, SOME_FRIENDS, SELF, or NO_FRIENDS (when the object can be
>   seen by a network only).
>
> The allow field must be specified when the friends value is set to
>   SOME_FRIENDS and must specify a comma-separated list of user IDs and
>   friend list IDs that 'can' see the post.

Try this instead, but you will need to know the friendlists ID for Family.

```
var theFriendLists = Api.Get(`me/friendlist`);
var theFriendsListIdForFamily = theFriendLists.Select item  where list_type=="family";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("value", "CUSTOM");
jsonObject.put("friends", "SOME_FRIENDS");
jsonObject.put("allow", theFriendsListIdForFamily);
parameters.putString("privacy", jsonObject.toString());
```